# is there a way to get device geolocation using C# 3.5?

Tags: c#, geolocation

all i can find are solutions that use the .Net 4.5 or greater, but im restricted to c#3.5.

the only solution available are in newer libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I see the GeoCoordinateWatcher only supports .NET 4 and up.

You should be able to use the [Sensor API Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318964(v=vs.85).aspx) to pinvoke the SensorAPI functionality from your C# project.

Also I would browse Nuget for geolocation library's that are available on .NET 3.5 in case someone has already build a library you can use that is 3.5 compatible.